# shortcut key for changing user in time of login

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

In windows xp it is possible to change the user at  login time by clicking

```
Alt+Ctrl+Del
```

Is there any shortcut for same purpose in windows 7 ?

Comment: Err, what? You press Ctrl+Alt+Del to log in, in both Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: no...in xp there opens a user selection window after pressing the shortcut but for win 7 it remains same

Comment: You can't log in to either operating system without specifying a user. This question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yes, you are correct. but can you please see the url : [Image](http://www.winsupersite.com/content/content/127384/reviews/winxp_2462_000b.gif)   when the OS prompt you for password then your limit is only to select a user and give password, but if you want to login as administrator then there is no option unless you open the window as [Img](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_oBVIi9wfV5A/SK2nEkpSpFI/AAAAAAAAAJQ/d3-CmRRajBI/s1600/Windows_XP_ctrl_alt_delete_logon.jpg)  by pressing alt+ctrl+del and insert the username. My question is is there any option in win7 for inserting username manually like 2nd url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get on-the-fly access to the user name & password dialog in Windows 7 (and Vista).

The only way of getting the user name and password to display will make you have to enter both details every time and you'll end up with a log on screen like this **every time** the logon screen appears.

[image: Sample Logon Screen]

If you really want to do this, then I'll suggest you take a look at [this howToGeek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-ubuntu-style-logons-in-windows-vista/). It was written with Windows Vista in mind but it works for Windows 7 as well.